# Cakephp 3.0: Finder query returns empty result

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Here is it:

```
$this->loadModel('IntAdmin');
$test = $this->IntAdmin->find('list', [
    'contain' => ['Sales', 'Accounts'],
    'conditions' => [
        'IntAdmin.status' => 'submitted',
        'IntAdmin.id IN' => [$picking_lists['picking_list']]
    ]
]);
pr($test);
exit;
```

In `$picking_lists`, this is what I have:

```
Array
(
    [picking_list] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 11
        )

)
```

This is `pr()` result:

```
Cake\ORM\Query Object
(
    [(help)] => This is a Query object, to get the results execute or iterate it.
    [sql] => SELECT IntAdmin.id AS `IntAdmin__id` FROM int_admins IntAdmin INNER JOIN sales Sales ON Sales.id = (IntAdmin.sale_id) INNER JOIN accounts Accounts ON Accounts.id = (IntAdmin.account_id) WHERE (IntAdmin.status = :c0 AND IntAdmin.id in (:c1))
    [params] => Array
        (
            [:c0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => submitted
                    [type] => string
                    [placeholder] => c0
                )

            [:c1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 10
                            [1] => 11
                        )

                    [type] => integer
                    [placeholder] => c1
                )

        )

    [defaultTypes] => Array
        (
            [IntAdmin.id] => integer
            [id] => integer
            [IntAdmin.user_id] => integer
            [user_id] => integer
            [IntAdmin.username] => string
            [username] => string
            [IntAdmin.sale_id] => integer
            [sale_id] => integer
            [IntAdmin.account_id] => integer
            [account_id] => integer
            [IntAdmin.pl_number] => string
            [pl_number] => string
            [IntAdmin.receiving_date] => datetime
            [receiving_date] => datetime
            [IntAdmin.status] => string
            [status] => string
        )

    [decorators] => 0
    [executed] => 
    [hydrate] => 1
    [buffered] => 1
    [formatters] => 1
    [mapReducers] => 0
    [contain] => Array
        (
            [Sales] => Array
                (
                )

            [Accounts] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [matching] => Array
        (
        )

    [extraOptions] => Array
        (
        )

    [repository] => App\Model\Table\IntAdminTable Object
        (
            [registryAlias] => IntAdmin
            [table] => int_admins
            [alias] => IntAdmin
            [entityClass] => App\Model\Entity\IntAdmin
            [associations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => users
                    [1] => accounts
                    [2] => sales
                )

            [behaviors] => Array
                (
                )

            [defaultConnection] => default
            [connectionName] => default
        )

)
```

I cannot find the problem here but the query returns empty result. Please help.

Please ask if you need more information.

Thanks

Comment: So, have you read what the output says in the key labeled `(help)`? Because you're not doing what it says there! On a side note, you shouldn't nest the `picking_list` array.

Comment: You should look at the _executed_ sql (and put it in the question). `'IntAdmin.id IN' => [$picking_lists['picking_list']]` <- there's an extra array there which may well cause a different query than you'd expect along the lines of `IntAdmin.id IN (Array)`. Should be `'IntAdmin.id IN' => $picking_lists['picking_list']`

Answer (score 0):

Use toArray to print result

```
$this->loadModel('IntAdmin');
$test = $this->IntAdmin->find('list', [
    'contain' => ['Sales', 'Accounts'],
    'conditions' => [
        'IntAdmin.status' => 'submitted',
        'IntAdmin.id IN' => [$picking_lists['picking_list']]
    ]
]);
pr($test->toArray());
exit;
```